# how to implement floating label

Tags: html, css

[image: google form]

how to implement floating label shown in image

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element to see how they do it?

Comment: @prince it is not superscript, it is floating label...it is achieved using custom css or material design css

Comment: What is superscript ?

Comment: There is no need to use special tags. It's just a label that moves around.

Comment: @HirenVaghasiya thanks for this information I thought that was superscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.position {
  background-color:white;
  position:relative;
  top:8px;
  left:28px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="position">
  &nbsp; Phone number (optional) &nbsp;
</div>
<input type="text" id="subscript-box" name="tb1" style="border-width: thin; width: 230px;height:22px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the text below or above the input box and move it around with `position: relative` via CSS.